# Pandas: Dataframe itertuples boolean series groupby optimization

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new in python.
I have data frame (DF) example:

| id | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | C |
| 2 | B |

I would like to add a column example A_flag group by id.
In the end I have data frame (DF):

| id | type | A_flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 1 | B | 1 |
| 2 | C | 0 |
| 2 | B | 0 |

I can do this in two step:

- `DF['A_flag_tmp'] = [1 if x.type=='A' else 0 for x in DF.itertuples()]`
- `DF['A_flag'] = DF.groupby(['id'])['A_flag_tmp'].transform(np.max)`

It's working, but it's very slowy for big data frame.
Is there any way to optimize this case ?
Thank's for help.

Comment: Just do `DF['A_flag_tmp'] = x["type"].eq("A")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your codes with slow iterative coding to fast vectorized coding by replacing your first step to generate a boolean series by Pandas built-in functions, e.g.

```
df['type'].eq('A')
```

Then, you can attach it to the groupby statement for second step, as follows:

```
df['A_flag'] = df['type'].eq('A').groupby(df['id']).transform('max').astype(int)
```

**Result**

```
print(df)


   id type  A_flag
0   1    A       1
1   1    B       1
2   2    C       0
3   2    B       0
```

In general, if you have more complicated conditions, you can also define it in vectorized way, eg. define the boolean series `m` by:

```
m = df['type'].eq('A') & df['type1'].gt(1)  | (df['type2'] != 0)
```

Then, use it in step 2 as follows:

```
m.groupby(df['id']).transform('max').astype(int)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I've one more question. How to do this when I have more complicated case for examle A_flag_tmp is created by 2 or 3 variables, for example DF['A_flag_tmp']=[1 if (x.type=='A' and x.type1==1 and x.etc.....) else 0 for x in DF.itertuples()]. I oversimplified the case.

Comment: @Maciej  You can construct the boolean series according to your required combination of conditions. e.g. for this case, use `m = df['type'].eq('A') & df['type1'].eq(1)` and then use `m.groupby(df['id']).transform('max').astype(int)`

Comment: @Maciej  Is that clear ?

Comment: it's clear, thanks :)